# Que n'avons-nous d'ailes

Tags: syntaxe

There's a pair of lines in the song *Loin de Nottingham* from the translated *Robin des bois* of Disney's:

> Que n'avons-nous d'ailes pour nous envoler
>
> Qui prendra pitié de nos larmes

I'm not quite sure how the first one works syntactically. Also, I've included the second in case the connection is something like "nos larmes (pour le fait) que n'avons-nous...".

For the syntax, it would seem to make sense if *que* were *pourquoi*, for example. But I'm not sure how to read *que* as a question word here, or if it's not a question, why this context would licence inversion. (For example, is this the *que* of exclamation, similar to "qu'il fait beau !"? If so, why the inversion?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Que" means basically "pourquoi", the reason of this interpretation being that it is used in a negative form.

> (TLFi) **C. − Conj. ou adv. exclam.
>
> 2. [Placé en tête de phrase, que indique un haut degré]
>
> b) Que + interr. ou exclam. nég.** Pourquoi.
> • Pour resserrer les nœuds de cette chaste famille, que ne donne-t-on en mariage le frère à la sœur et la sœur au frère? (Chateaubr., Fragm. Génie, 1800, p. 165).
> • Que ne suis-je déjà au lieu de mon repos! (Chateaubr., Natchez, 1826, p. 389).
> • « Ah, pensait le plus jeune, que n'ai-je auprès de moi mon chien aux dents fraîches, pour lui faire un licol de mes bras!... » (Montherl., Bestiaires, 1926, p. 576).
> • Qu'allons-nous visiter sa cellule! Elle est vide (Saint-Exup., Terre hommes, 1939, p. 187).

This type of question is however more or less rhetorical, to the point sometimes of being  ended even by an exclamation point; it is not an actual question but the expression of a regret.  ([list of examples for "que n'avons-nous"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22que%20n%27avons%20nous%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

([ref. Oeuvres complètes de Fénelon - Volume 8](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Oeuvres_compl%C3%A8tes_de_F%C3%A9nelon/mtNxDeaaPcMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22que+n%27avons+nous%22&pg=PA480&printsec=frontcover)) ... et que n'avons - nous mon caprice , ma colère , mon amour - propre , pas fait pour le contenter ? Quel regret , quelle et la seule considération des hommes me fait peine , de se voir assez malheureuse , pour entreprendre , n'est pas ...

([ref. Oeuvres complètes de Chateaubriand augm. d'un essai ...](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Oeuvres_compl%C3%A8tes_de_Chateaubriand_augm/TrpIAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22que+n%27avons+nous%22&pg=RA1-PA177&printsec=frontcover)) Autre grief : si nous voulions sincèrement la paix , que n'avons - nous accepté la médiation de l'Angleterre ? Nous n'avons jamais refusé ses bons offices pour un accord amical ; quant à la médiation , nous n'avions de jugement à subir ...

There is no connection with the second line, which is a true question. You could put this sentence as follows instead, but this is far from being a universal equivalent;  sentences of this type require other turns   at times.

- Que c'est regrettable que nous n'ayons pas d'ailes pour nous envoler
- Comme c'est regrettable que… (*alternative*)

Note: As added in the comments by [**user jlliagre**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51879/que-navons-nous-dailes/51880?noredirect=1#comment107573_51880) this is not a turn used in usual conversation. However, it will not sound out of place in the mouth of a very learned person commenting on important matters, especially matters dear to their heart (politicians, historians, journalists, scientists, etc).

Comment: You might want to add that this turn is very literary and unused in regular conversation.